# HTML5 document outline and semantics

Tags: html

I have been using some elements of HTML5 for awhile, but never got around to really getting myself into it, so am making it a priority to get my bum in gear.

I have read up about every aspect I can find, and built myself a little tester. I have run it through an outliner tool and everything seems to come out trumps. Just wondered if anyone would be as kind to take a look at my full test document to see if I am overlooking something /  doing anything drastically wrong.

```
<body>
    <!-- Header --> 
    <header>
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" />
        <h1>Slogan</h1>
        <nav>
            <header><h2 class="hide-element">Navigation</h2></header>
            <ul>
                <li>Nav Item</li>
                <li>Nav Item</li>
                <li>Nav Item</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>       
    <!-- Main Content -->       
    <section id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h2>Page Heading</h2>
        </header>               
        <section>               
            <h2 class="hide-element">Section Heading</h2>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h3>Sub Heading</h3>
                    <time datetime="2013-02-08">February 8th 2013</time>
                </header>
                <p>Section Text</p>
                <footer>
                    Like Button
                </footer>
            </article>

            <article>
                <header>
                    <h3>Sub Heading</h3>
                </header>
                <p>Section Text</p>
                <figure>
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <footer>
                    Like Button
                </footer>
            </article>              
        </section>

        <aside>
            <h2 class="hide-element">Sidebar</h2>
            <nav>
                <header>
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                </header>
                <ul>
                    <li>Sidebar Nav Item</li>
                    <li>Sidebar Nav Item</li>
                    <li>Sidebar Nav Item</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>            
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->     
    <footer>
        <nav>
            <h3>Links</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <h3>Social</h3>
            <a href="">Link to Twitter</a>
            <a href="">Link to Facebook</a>
        </section>
        <p class="copyright">&#169; Copyright 2013</p>
        <p class="credit"><a href="" target="_blank">Credit</a></p>
    </footer>   
</body>
```

**Update**

Added  around h2 inside  tag. Didnt realise you could have  inside . Thanks

Changed div#wrapper to section.

Comment: You should probably add `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html lang="en">` at the top, and `</html>` at the end.

Comment: This might be better suited to the code review stack exchange http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In html5, the h1-h6 tags don't work the same way they did in html4, you can have a whole stack of h1-h6 per sectioning element (section/nav/etc..) so pretty much all your h2/h3 should be h1. Beside that, a suggestion would be to use the <small> tag for the copyright.

Comment: Hi Roger C. Thanks. I read that you can just use h1 for every heading but it doesn't list well with legacy browsers. Would your suggestion work okay for all browsers? Also, would small be best for just copyright, or credit as well?

Comment: I personally tried it and it works well with all browsers. I'm not sure if search engines likes that though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` element is not [sectioning content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#sectioning-content), so that means you have two `header` elements at the same outline level, one a direct child of `body` and one a direct child of `div#wrapper`.  This certainly isn't invalid or even [discouraged in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element), but it does seem a little odd.  If you want it to be a header for the content in `#wrapper` and not just a second header for the whole page, then your `#wrapper` element should be a `section` or an `article`.  Other than that I think the markup structure is fine.